# When does this cron job get executed?

Tags: unix, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I see this cron setting in a crontab and I am curious as to when the script actually gets executed.

```
8 10 * * 6 expr `date +\%W` \% 2 == 1 >/dev/null || /path/to/script/scriptToRun.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a picky syntax...

```
8 10 * * 6 expr `date +\%W` \% 2 == 1 >/dev/null || /path/to/script/scriptToRun.sh
```

First, the cronjob:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
 8 10  *  *  6
```

So in this case it means that the cronjob gets executed **every Saturday at 10.08**.

Then, `man date` says:

> %W
>
> week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)

`$(date +\%W) \% 2 == 1 >/dev/null` means: if the week number is not multiple of 2, then send the output to dev/null. Otherwise, proceed normally.

So the script gets executed **every other Saturday at 10.08**.